# Odd behavior on for loop spawning (background) threads

Tags: c#

Feel free to run the code

```
Thread thread;
for (int i = 6000; i < 6006; i++)
{
    //Thread.Sleep(1);
    thread = new Thread(() => derp(i));

    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}

private void derp(int a)
{
    MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
}
```

It works fine with the thread sleep though, anyone got an explanation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not odd, and its something you will come to learn. The concept is called Capture and Closure

[Closure (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))

> In programming languages, a closure (also lexical closure or function
>   closure) is a technique for implementing lexically scoped name binding
>   in a language with first-class functions. Operationally, a closure is
>   a record storing a function[a] together with an environment.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) The
>   environment is a mapping associating each free variable of the
>   function (variables that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing
>   scope) with the value or reference to which the name was bound when
>   the closure was created.[b] A closure—unlike a plain function—allows
>   the function to access those captured variables through the closure's
>   copies of their values or references, even when the function is
>   invoked outside their scope.

The fix to this problem is pretty simple. Instead of capturing the indexer of the "for" loop, we create a local variable which holds a copy of the value.

```
for (int i = 6000; i < 6006; i++)
{
    var capturedIndex = i;
    thread = new Thread(() => derp(capturedIndex ));

    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}
```